# Как рандомно разбросать изображения на странице?

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер, подскажите как рандомно разбросать массив изображений на странице, но так, чтобы они были в одном родительском элементе и не выходили за пределы + не ложились на друг друга. Без применения библиотек и фреймворков. Пробовал вот так, но тогда накладывается друг на друга, и контроль области не самый лучший.

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  var rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}

const x = randomInteger(0, 900);
var y = randomInteger(0, 280);
img.style.transform = `translate(${x}px,${y}px)`;
```

Comment: Вы сами хоть пытались?

Comment: Задача простая. В чем конкретно загвоздка?

Comment: @Hipster Добавил листинг в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Перемешайте массив изображений, а потом добавьте их `appendChild` к нужному элементу. Все остальные задачи отображения должны ложиться на CSS.

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}
```